# Binary operator-overloading string-class for primitives

Tags: c++, string, operator-overloading, string-concatenation

I have one simple qusetion about the std::string class.

Why isn't + overloaded for primitives so that strings easily can be concatenated?

For instance - if I have a double

```
double d = 1000.5:
```

And a string

```
std::string s = "my value is ";
```

And I want to concatenate this string with the double in an easy manner

```
s = s + d;
```

And the result should be:

```
my value is 1000.5
```

This is easily made in languages such as Java

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    double d = 1000.5;
    String s = "my Value is ";
    s += d;
    System.out.println(s);
}
```

Instead this is an example of how to do it in c++

```
int main() {
   double d = 1000.5;
   std::ostringstream strs;
   strs << d;
   std::string s = "My value is " + strs.str();
   cout << s;

   return 0;
}
```

Its not complicated but it would be much simpler if concatenation in the "java-way" was allowed.

Comment: In C++11 you can do `"My value is " + std::to_string(d)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is easy enough to do without all the `stringstream` business. Use [`std::to_string`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/to_string)

```
std::string s = "my value is " + std::to_string(d);
```

---

Or for pre-C++11 compilers, `boost::lexical_cast` can be used

```
std::string s = "my value is " + boost::lexical_cast<std::string>(d);
```

Comment: I got a compilation-error in VC++ with the to_string(double d)-method: ambigious call to overloaded function. But then I saw in the defintion that the signature is a **long double**. So now it seems to work :-)

Comment: what header do I need for boost? I need the 2nd solution for MinGW

Comment: @user3155478 It works with a `double` argument on VS2013. Earlier versions of VS lacked all the overloads for `to_string` resulting in ambiguities. It'll work if you `std::to_string(static_cast<long double>(d))`. The header for `lexical_cast` is `boost/lexical_cast.hpp`

Comment: the header doesnt seem to exist in my MinGW-version

Comment: @user3155478 You mean `lexical_cast.hpp`? AFAIK MinGW doesn't ship with boost. You'll need to download it from boost.org

Comment: thanks - the first solution will do since I work more often in Visual Studio.

Comment: @user3155478 Unless you're using some really old MinGW distribution, you should be able to use the C++11 solution on that too. You'll have to pass the `-std=c++11` switch to the compiler to enable C++11 mode.

Answer (score 2):

You can easily implement it.

```
template <typename T, typename = typename std::enable_if<std::is_arithmetic<T>::value>::type>
std::string& operator += (std::string& string, const T& number)
{
    return string += std::to_string(number);
}
```

Comment: very interesting implementation!

Answer (score 1):

Formatting rapidly becomes complicated - in some parts of the world the number should look like "1000,5", for example. So `stringstream` is available for formatted output, and `string` just handles simple string operations, including string concatenation.